# Retrieving an extended attribute that extends Site/Default

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I have a small problem using the Extended Attributes feature in Mura CMS. I have added a global extended attribute to Site/Default, but I am clueless how to retrieve it in my application. For normal content you would do `$.content().getValue('namespace')` but how does this work for an extended attribute within the site settings? I tried `$.getValue('namespace')` and `$.siteConfig('namespace')` but none worked.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Site/Default extended attribute, you should be able to access `$.siteConfig('attName')` ... so I would double check that it's not actually working. Maybe you accidentally typed the attributeName incorrectly?

To access any attribute, including extended attributes, these should all work:

```
$.siteConfig().getValue('attName')
$.siteConfig().get('attName')  // <- in the latest version
$.siteConfig('attName')
```

This syntax should work on pretty much any bean within Mura CMS.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Yes, thanks! It did work, still a mystery what happened yesterday but I think everything just points to a typo after all. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to call `getValue('namespace')` on `$.siteConfig()`, so it would be

```
$.siteConfig().getValue('namespace')
```

Would be cool to have the getValue method for site settings available on the global Mura Scope, so you would have the mura scope as the site layer, and use $.content() as the content layer. As in - it would make sense.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but please understand the `$` is its own scope ... shorthand for the `mura` scope as you pointed out. It has several other 'subscopes' such as: `globalConfig()`, `siteConfig()`, `content()`, `currentUser()`, etc.